# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, cgimage

I'm trying to crop an image into a square, but once I actually try to do the crop by using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(), this line crashes. I set breakpoints and made sure that the arguments passed into this function are not nil.

I'm fairly new to programming and Swift, but have searched around and haven't found any solution to my problem.

The failure reason:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func cropImageToSquare(imageData: NSData) -> NSData {

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    let contextImage : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!)
    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    let imageDimension: CGFloat = contextSize.height
    let posY : CGFloat = (contextSize.height + (contextSize.width - contextSize.height)/2)
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, posY, imageDimension, imageDimension)

    // error on line below: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(contextImage.CGImage, rect)!
    let croppedImage : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: image!.imageOrientation)

    let croppedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 1.0)

    return croppedImageData!

}
```

Comment: I would wager that `rect` is not right. I'm not sure what you're doing, but you're setting it to the height plus half the difference between the width and height (which, alone doesn't make sense to me), but then trying to get a rect that starts at that `posY`, but then is again the height of the image. So, `posY` plus that weird height probably yields a `CGRect` that is not within the size of the original image. I bet `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` is failing because it can't use the `rect` you passed to it.

Comment: Also, but unrelated, you're also converting data to `UIImage`, getting its `CGImage`, creating another `UIImage` from that, and then getting `CGImage` again. That all seems unnecessarily convoluted. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `contextImage`, but I'd retire that and just use your `image.CGImage` in your call to `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`.

Comment: What I was trying to do with `posY` was to crop a square from the center of the image, not from the top. Also, although I am restricting to Portrait-only images, printing out `contextSize` would give me the height and width reversed. (The height was actually less than the width, for some reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses a lot of force-unwrapping with `!`s. I would recommend avoiding this — the compiler is trying to help you write code that won't crash. Use optional chaining with `?`, and `if let` / `guard let`, instead.

The `!` on that particular line is hiding an issue where CGImageCreateWithImageInRect might return nil. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect) explains that this happens when the `rect` is not correctly inside the image bounds. Your code works for images in portrait orientation, but not landscape.

Furthermore, there's a convenient function provided by AVFoundation which can automatically find the right rectangle for you to use, called `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`. No need to do the calculations manually :-)

Here's what I would recommend:

```
import AVFoundation

extension UIImage
{
    func croppedToSquare() -> UIImage
    {
        guard let cgImage = self.CGImage else { return self }

        // Note: self.size depends on self.imageOrientation, so we use CGImageGetWidth/Height here.
        let boundingRect = CGRect(
            x: 0, y: 0,
            width: CGImageGetWidth(cgImage),
            height: CGImageGetHeight(cgImage))

        // Crop to square (1:1 aspect ratio) and round the resulting rectangle to integer coordinates.
        var cropRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), boundingRect)
        cropRect.origin.x = ceil(cropRect.origin.x)
        cropRect.origin.y = ceil(cropRect.origin.y)
        cropRect.size.width = floor(cropRect.size.width)
        cropRect.size.height = floor(cropRect.size.height)

        guard let croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgImage, cropRect) else {
            assertionFailure("cropRect \(cropRect) was not inside \(boundingRect)")
            return self
        }

        return UIImage(CGImage: croppedImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
    }
}

// then:
let croppedImage = myUIImage.croppedToSquare()
```

Comment: Thanks @jtbandes. I did not think of using `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`. What I don't understand is, how does the image get cropped in the center? I don't understand how this code makes that happen correctly.

Comment: `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect` centers it automatically.

Comment: Oh, how convenient! That's awesome. Thank you so much.